# Why does Safari 6 scroll to the bottom of the page when viewing Google search results?

Tags: applications, macos, safari

When I use the pagination at the bottom of Google search results pages to browse through the results, Safari 6 on OS X Mountain Lion automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page. Doesn't happen with every page, just most result pages. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Mountain Lion has introduced a new way for quick scolling which brings quite strange results in Safari.

Here is the explanation extracted from [this](http://www.macstories.net/mac/mountain-lion-the-macstories-review/) Macstories review of ML:

> On Mountain Lion, if you perform a quick scrolling gesture three times in a row the scrolling speed will ramp up to let you reach the end of a document quickly.